# Backend not connecting to frontend, heroku and surge

Tags: node.js, heroku, backend

I've deployed both my backend and frontend, but my frontend won't connect to my nodejs express backend, giving me the cors error. Everything works fine when run locally.
Heres the code to my backend.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const StudentVue = require('studentvue.js')
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
const url = 'https://md-mcps-psv.edupoint.com/';

app.options('*', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.end();
  });
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/done', async (req, res)=>{

    StudentVue.login(url, req.body.name.toString(), req.body.password.toString()).then(client =>{
        client.getGradebook().then(grades => {
            let parsed = JSON.parse(grades)
            if(parsed.RT_ERROR){
                res.json({
                    message:"Invalid username or password"
                })
            }else{ 
                res.json(parsed.Gradebook.Courses.Course)
            }

        })
    })
        
    
})
```

errors are

```
VM378:1 POST https://mcpshelper-server.herokuapp.com/ 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ VM378:1
(anonymous) @ client.js:15
mcpsvuehelper.surge.sh/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: What are you using for Front-End?

Comment: Could you post the Procfile you are using in here?

Comment: Im using surge for the front end and I don't have a procfile